# Specialize member pointer template argument resolution

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Having guard class on C++11 that is responsible to invoke some member function on scope exit:

```
template <class T, void (T::*op)()>
struct Guard
{
    Guard(T*g):
        _g(g){}
    ~Guard()
    {
        (_g->*op)();
    }
    T*_g;
};
```

Usage is very simple:

```
typedef Guard<Foo, &Foo::bar> FooGuard;
...
FooGuard g(&foo);
```

My question originated from existing `shared_ptr<Foo>`. How to create specialization that keeps `shared_ptr<T>` instead of `T*`

What I've already tried:

```
template <class T, void (T::*op)()>
struct Guard<std::shared_ptr<T>, op>
{
    Guard(std::shared_ptr<T>& g):
        _g(g){}
    ~Guard()
    {
        ((*_g).*op)();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> _g;
};
```

But during compilation on `G<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, &Foo::bar> g2(foo);` have foreseeable got:

> error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__thiscall std::shared_ptr::* )(void)'

Comment: `_g->op();` will work?

Comment: `struct Guard<std::shared_ptr<T>, op>` is not a valid specialization

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki i know, so what is your solution to create Guard class that works on pointers and smart-pointers?

Comment: @Dewfy make `void (T::*op)()` a constructor parameter

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki good try, place it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @PiotrSkotnicki already pointed out, your specialization is not valid.
You could use something like the following, however the interface does not look that nice:

```
template <class T, class U, void (U::*op)()>
struct Guard
{
    Guard(T*g):
        _g(g){}
    ~Guard()
    {
        std::cout << "normal guard" << std::endl;
        (_g->*op)();
    }
    T*_g;
};


template <class T, class U, void (U::*op)()>
struct Guard<std::shared_ptr<T>, U, op>
{
    Guard(std::shared_ptr<T>& g):
        _g(g){}
    ~Guard()
    {
        std::cout << "shared_ptr guard" << std::endl;
        ((*_g).*op)();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> _g;
};
```

**Demo:**

```
struct Foo
{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    {
        typedef Guard<Foo, Foo, &Foo::bar> FooGuard;
        FooGuard g(&foo);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    {
        typedef Guard<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, Foo, &Foo::bar> FooGuard;
        FooGuard g(foo_ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
normal guard
Foo::bar()
shared_ptr guard
Foo::bar()
```

<kbd>[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e085aUebXnGLC289)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using lambda functions instead and capture by value:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct Guard
{
    typedef std::function<void()> func_type;

    Guard( const func_type& f ): func(f) {}
    ~Guard() { if (func) func(); }

    func_type func;
};

struct Foo
{
    void bar() {}
};

int main()
{
    auto foo_ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    Guard g([foo_ptr](){ foo_ptr->bar(); }); // note the capture by value
}
```

Note that you are free to capture by reference too, if you want to guard an instance allocated on the stack for example.

Comment: well, solution is agile, but I need care about clean operation on each `Guard` creation, instead of define it once

Comment: @Dewfy Not sure I understand your comment; how is using pointers and partial template specialisation cleaner than this?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick to the ugly way, I would suggest using deleters:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

template < class T, void (T::*op)() >
struct Guard
{
    Guard( T *p ): ptr( p, [](T*){} ) {}
    Guard( const std::shared_ptr<T>& p ): ptr(p) {}

    ~Guard() { if (ptr) ((*ptr).*op)(); }

    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo( const char* n ): name(n) {}
    void bar() { printf("Hello from %s\n",name.c_str()); }

    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    auto foo1 = Foo("Bob");
    auto foo2 = std::make_shared<Foo>("Alice");

    Guard<Foo,&Foo::bar> g1(&foo1), g2(foo2);
}
```

Comment: Actually I'd like to complete this with specialization, so end user has transparent declaration of guard object for many cases. That is why I'm going to accept @m.s. as closest to my idea. But anyway +1 since it works correctly